# Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile throws CryptographicException

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile throws CryptographicException.

We uploaded a management certificate and all the Azure APIs are returning results but Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile throws following exception:

> importSystem.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An internal error occurred.
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] awData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password)
>
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.PublishSettingsImporter.PublishSubscriptionToAzureSubscription(PublishDataPublishProfile profile, PublishDataPublishProfileSubscription s) in e:\projects\azure-sdk-tools\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.Utilities\Common\PublishSettingsImporter.cs:line 56
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.WindowsAzureProfile.ImportPublishSettings(String fileName) in e:\projects\azure-sdk-tools\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.Utilities\Common\WindowsAzureProfile.cs:line 293

Comment: Thanks, we'll take a look.

Comment: You mention uploading a certificate, but generating a poublishsettings file actualy creates a new management certificate in Azure.  So, did you use set-azurecertificate to add the certificate you uploaded  to a subscription and THEN try import-azurepuiblishsettingsfile, or are you using import on a machine that has no previous subscriptions imported?  Just trying to figure out how uploading a certificate is related to using the import-azurepublishsettingsfile command.