# Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile throws CryptographicException, Internal Error when called from IIS

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am experiencing a problem similar to the one described here:

[Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile throws CryptographicException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040425/import-azurepublishsettingsfile-throws-cryptographicexception)

We are calling Powershell from IIS to programmatically deploy VMs. Part of this process involves loading new Publish Settings Files in for new customers. We are getting the following error when attempting to do so:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile : An internal error occurred.

At C:\WebApps\Provisioning\PowerShellScripts\vmDeploy.ps1:152 char:2
+     Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile ($outputDir + "\" + $azSettingsFile) 
-ErrorActi ...
+    
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) 
[Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile], CryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Subscription.ImportAzurePublishSettingsCommand
```

I have a hunch this has something to do with the user space, as if I run exactly the same script from an interactive PS session, on the same server, it works fine.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Edit: Stack trace from Powershell:

```
PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An internal error occurred.

                           at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
                           at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
                           at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
                           at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password)
                           at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.PublishSettingsImporter.PublishSubscriptionToAzureSubscription(PublishDataPublishProfile profile, PublishDataPublishProfileSubscription s) in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.Utilities\Common\PublishSettingsImporter.cs:line 56
                           at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
                           at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
                           at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
                           at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.WindowsAzureProfile.ImportPublishSettings(String fileName) in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.Utilities\Common\WindowsAzureProfile.cs:line 293
                           at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Subscription.ImportAzurePublishSettingsCommand.ImportFile(String fileName) in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands\Subscription\ImportAzurePublishSettings.cs:line 95
                           at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Subscription.ImportAzurePublishSettingsCommand.ExecuteCmdlet() in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands\Subscription\ImportAzurePublishSettings.cs:line 46
                           at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletBase.ProcessRecord() in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.Utilities\Common\CmdletBase.cs:line 96
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile], 
                        CryptographicException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Subscription.ImportAzurePublishSettingsCommand
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\WebApps\Provisioning\PowerShellScripts\vmDeploy.ps1: line 163
PipelineIterationInfo : {}





MyCommand             : Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile
BoundParameters       : {}
UnboundArguments      : {}
ScriptLineNumber      : 163
OffsetInLine          : 2
HistoryId             : 1
ScriptName            : C:\WebApps\Provisioning\PowerShellScripts\vmDeploy.ps1
Line                  :     Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile ($outputDir + "\" + 
                        $azSettingsFile) -ErrorAction Stop

PositionMessage       : At C:\WebApps\Provisioning\PowerShellScripts\vmDeploy.ps
                        1:163 char:2
                        +     Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile ($outputDir + "\" 
                        + $azSettingsFile) -ErrorActi ...
                        +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
PSScriptRoot          : C:\WebApps\Provisioning\PowerShellScripts
PSCommandPath         : C:\WebApps\Provisioning\PowerShellScripts\vmDeploy.ps1
InvocationName        : Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile
PipelineLength        : 0
PipelinePosition      : 0
ExpectingInput        : False
CommandOrigin         : Internal
DisplayScriptPosition : 



00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000


Message        : An internal error occurred.

Data           : {}
InnerException : 
TargetSite     : Void ThrowCryptographicException(Int32)
StackTrace     :    at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
                    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle&pCertCtx)
                    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
                    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.PublishSettingsImporter.PublishSubscriptionToAzureSubscription(PublishDataPublishProfile profile, PublishDataPublishProfileSubscription s) in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.Utilities\Common\PublishSettingsImporter.cs:line 56
                    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
                    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1collection)
                    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1source)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.WindowsAzureProfile.ImportPublishSettings(String fileName) in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.Utilities\Common\WindowsAzureProfile.cs:line 293
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Subscription.ImportAzurePublishSettingsCommand.ImportFile(String fileName) in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands\Subscription\ImportAzurePublishSettings.cs:line 95
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Subscription.ImportAzurePublishSettingsCommand.ExecuteCmdlet() in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands\Subscription\ImportAzurePublishSettings.cs:line 46
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletBase.ProcessRecord() in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.Utilities\Common\CmdletBase.cs:line 96
HelpLink       : 
Source         : mscorlib
HResult        : -2146893792
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

We changed the user context of the IIS app pool to a local administrator, and this resolved the issue. This suggests that the problem was access to the cryptographic store from the previous context. However the error and stack trace are too vague to confirm this hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Using the WAML libraries for Compute, I'm able to deploy - however, I have to use slightly different credential loading:

`X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(
    Convert.FromBase64String(encodedCertificate),
    "MyPrivateKey",
    X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);`

Essentially I need to tell the system to load from the machine key set (even though my cert is local), and then the CryptographicException goes away.

I'm guessing this may be somewhat similar - even though you are using PowerShell, it is built on top of the WAML preview.

Answer (score 0):

We had our build agent running on an Azure VM, it had been working fine but suddenly stopped working one day, apparently without any reason with the above error.

Logging on to the VM and running `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "FileName"` manually would run perfectly.

We found that our build agent was setup incorrectly and running under a user account who's MSDN credentials had changed.

We solved the problem firstly by restarting the VM - this will kill any Build Agent Processes running under other user accounts (in our case there was one and it was stopping us from running the next step below)

Next, it's best if you install the build agent as a service by running the script (as an administrator)
`<agent home>/bin/service.install.bat file`

You can check that the service is install by checking in `Computer Management -> Services` dialog that a Service called "Team City Agent" (or something similar is running), assuming everything else is setup ok your builds should start working (or at least get past the cryptographic error above :) )

More info can be found here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents